# Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'productsList' and 'String'

Tags: arrays, json, swift, segue

I am trying to send data from one VC to the next but I get the error stated in the title in my last function where I declare the updaterId constant. I would prefer they both be of type productsList considering that is helping me parse my JSON. I know there are quotation marks in that line of code but I'm just using a string as an example here.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage

class ListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet var tableViewProducts: UITableView!
    var delegate: ListViewController?

    var ref:DatabaseReference?
    var databaseHandle: DatabaseHandle?

    var postData = [productsList]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("AudioDB")
        loadProducts()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return postData.count
    }

    func loadProducts() {
        ref?.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            var newSweets = [productsList]()

            for post in snapshot.children {
                let postObject = productsList(snapshot: post as! DataSnapshot)
                newSweets.append(postObject)
                print(self.postData)

            }
            self.postData = newSweets
            self.tableViewProducts.reloadData()
        }) { (error:Error) in
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: self)
    }

    //This places the text on the ViewControllerTableViewCell
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

        let sweet = postData[indexPath.row]

        cell.idLbl.text = sweet.id
        cell.nameLbl.text = sweet.p_name

        if let profileImageUrl = sweet.image {
            let url = URL(string: profileImageUrl)
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.productImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                }
            }).resume()
        }
        return cell
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? ProductViewController,
            let index = tableViewProducts.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row {

            // Check whether postData array count is greater than index
            let updaterId = postData.count > index ? postData[index] : ""

            // Initialize "productsList" instance and assign the id value and send this object to next view controller
            let updater = productsList(id: updaterId, p_name: String)
            updater.id = updaterId
            destination.updater = updater
        }
    }
}
```

Here is Products list:

```
struct productsList {

    let id: String!
    let p_name: String!
    let image: String!


    init(id: String, p_name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.p_name = p_name
        self.image = p_name

    }

    init (snapshot:DataSnapshot) {
        var dict = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
        id = dict["id"] as! String
        p_name = dict["p_name"] as! String
        image = dict["image"] as! String

    }
```

Comment: What is `productsList`?

Comment: FYI - Class/struct/enum names should start with uppercase letters.

Comment: It is my struct to help me parse my json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
let updaterId = postData.count > index ? postData[index] : ""
```

`postData` is declared as being an array of `productsList`, so `postData[index]` is a `productsList`. But `""` is a String. They need to be the same type — either both must be Strings or both must be `productsList` instances.

You probably meant for both of them to be strings; you probably meant

```
let updaterId = postData.count > index ? postData[index].id : ""
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem to want to get the user id, change:

```
let updaterId = postData.count > index ? postData[index] : ""
```

to:

```
let updaterId = postData.count > index ? postData[index].id : ""
```

This gives you a `String` on both sides of the `:`.